# How is $\pi : S^1 \times I \mapsto B^2$, defined as $\pi (x,t)=(1-t)x $ a closed map?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the map $\pi : S^1 \times I \mapsto B^2$, defined as $\pi (x,t)=(1-t)x $

Here $B^2 $ is the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R }^2 $, $S^1 $ is the unit circle.

How is it a closed map?

I suppose I will have to start with a closed set in $ S^1 \times I $, but I'm not sure what they look like. And how is it mapped to a closed set in $B^2 $?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a continuous function from a compact space ($S^1 \times I$) to a Hausdorff (even metric) space $B^2$.

So $C$ is closed means $C$ is compact and so $\pi[C]$ is compact as well, and thus closed (as compact sets are closed in a Hausdorff space and a continuous image of a compact set is compact.)